# How to filter site.xml when building site with maven-site-plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-site-plugin

I am building a site with maven-site-plugin.

I included a placeholder in my site.xml (${env.git_url}) which should be replaced with an environment variable unfortunately this does not work:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.6:site (default-site) on project setup-tool-api: Execution default-site of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.6:site failed: Illegal character in path at index 1: ${env.git_url} -> [Help 1]
```

Here are a snippet of the command executed:

```
export git_url="some-url"
mvn site
```

Here is an extract of the site.xml file

```
<menu name="Overview" inherit="top">
    <item name="Sources" href="${env.git_url}"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: Please elaborate more

Comment: `this does not seems to work` What ate you trying that does not work? Please include more data such as your pom.xml

Comment: Unless you don't provide more details, no one will able to help you.

Comment: @Michael-O I have provided more details. Is it enough now ?

Comment: @Abbadon, upgrade to MSITE 3.7 and check with `help:system` whether your var is avaiable to Maven.

Answer (score 1):

I do not fully understand why is it happening, as this syntax is correct, however, if you use early interpolation, plugin should start work smoothly. To use it, add `this.` to your property path:

```
<menu name="Overview" inherit="top">
    <item name="Sources" href="${this.env.git_url}"/>
</menu>
```